# Bitbake: "Nothing PROVIDES" error

Tags: package, qemu, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm new to Yocto and Bitbake. I'm running my yocto machine through a qemu emulator on Ubuntu and attempting to use the `meta-selftest` layer to get a sense of how to install new layers. I have downloaded the `meta-selftest` files into the directory where the rest of the `meta-` directories are, and added the path to the `meta-selftest` directory to the `bblayers.conf` file. Running `bitbake-layers show-layers` command gives the output

```
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  /home/[my name]/Documents/poky/meta         5
meta-poky             /home/[my name]/Documents/poky/meta-poky    5
meta-yocto-bsp        /home/[my name]/Documents/poky/meta-yocto-bsp  5
meta-selftest         /home/[my name]/Documents/poky/meta-selftest  5
```

however, when I try to run `bitbake meta-selftest` I get the error:

```
Loading cache: 100% 
Loaded 1294 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'meta-selftest'

Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

What does this error mean? I checked `meta-selftest`'s dependencies, and it doesn't have any, so I get the sense this error isn't saying there is a dependency issue, but I can't find any clear documentation on what this error is telling me. I get the vague sense it means that bitbake can't find `meta-selftest`, but `show-layers` contradicts that by listing it with the correct path.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

-Patches

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't bitbake a layer, you bitbake a recipe from that layer. 
Try a `bitbake test-empty-image` for example. That is an image recipe provided by that layer.

Explore the `meta-selftest` directory and look for `.bb` files, the recipes. Those can be build using bitbake.

I recommend having a look at the quick start guide: <strike>http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html</strike>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Reading through the quick start guide (mostly Ch 4), it seems like adding the name of the layer to `bblayers.conf` should allow the `bitbake` command to build that package into the image. Reading further makes it seem like the `meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato.bb` should be duplicated and edited to include packages (in my case adding `IMAGE_INSTALL += "meta-selftest"`), however attempting to build this image leads to failure due to the `Nothing PROVIDES` error again. When I try running `bitbake` on my actual package, `swupdate_2017.11`, I get the same err.

Comment: Again, you don't install the `meta-selftest` in the image, you can install a package provided by that layer, eg `selftest-ed`. A package has the same name as the recipe (selftest-ed_1.14.1.bb).
`IMAGE_INSTALL += "selftest-ed"`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need bitbake the layers name.

Please check in meta-selftest dir and try to find the *.bb file (it's recipes). And try again with " bitbake recipes_name.bb "